# NHibernate LINQ Query - object references an unsaved transient instance - Without saving

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I've got a weird exception when I execute an nHibernate LINQ query. 
If I write 


`var address = new Address {Id = Guid.Empty};
session.Query().Where(x=> x == address).ToList();`

Than I get

> object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient
>   instance before flushing or set cascade action for the property to
>   something that would make it autosave. Type: DomainModel.Address,
>   Entity: DomainModel.Address
>
> at
>   NHibernate.Engine.ForeignKeys.GetEntityIdentifierIfNotUnsaved(String
>   entityName, Object entity, ISessionImplementor session)    at
>   NHibernate.Type.EntityType.GetIdentifier(Object value,
>   ISessionImplementor session)    at
>   NHibernate.Type.ManyToOneType.NullSafeSet(IDbCommand cmd, Object
>   value, Int32 index, ISessionImplementor session)    at
>   NHibernate.Param.NamedParameterSpecification.Bind(IDbCommand command,
>   IList`1 multiSqlQueryParametersList, Int32 singleSqlParametersOffset,
>   IList`1 sqlQueryParametersList, QueryParameters queryParameters,
>   ISessionImplementor session)    at
>   NHibernate.Param.NamedParameterSpecification.Bind(IDbCommand command,
>   IList`1 sqlQueryParametersList, QueryParameters queryParameters,
>   ISessionImplementor session)    at
>   NHibernate.SqlCommand.SqlCommandImpl.Bind(IDbCommand command,
>   ISessionImplementor session)    at
>   NHibernate.Loader.Loader.PrepareQueryCommand(QueryParameters
>   queryParameters, Boolean scroll, ISessionImplementor session)    at
>   NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQuery(ISessionImplementor session,
>   QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies)    at
>   NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(ISessionImplementor
>   session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies)    at
>   NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoList(ISessionImplementor session,
>   QueryParameters queryParameters)    at
>   NHibernate.Loader.Loader.ListIgnoreQueryCache(ISessionImplementor
>   session, QueryParameters queryParameters)    at
>   NHibernate.Loader.Loader.List(ISessionImplementor session,
>   QueryParameters queryParameters, ISet`1 querySpaces, IType[]
>   resultTypes)    at
>   NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.Loader.QueryLoader.List(ISessionImplementor
>   session, QueryParameters queryParameters)    at
>   NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QueryTranslatorImpl.List(ISessionImplementor
>   session, QueryParameters queryParameters)    at
>   NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLQueryPlan.PerformList(QueryParameters
>   queryParameters, ISessionImplementor session, IList results)    at
>   NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.List(IQueryExpression queryExpression,
>   QueryParameters queryParameters, IList results)    at
>   NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.List(IQueryExpression
>   queryExpression, QueryParameters parameters)    at
>   NHibernate.Impl.ExpressionQueryImpl.List()    at
>   NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.ExecuteQuery(NhLinqExpression
>   nhLinqExpression, IQuery query, NhLinqExpression nhQuery)    at
>   NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression)
>   at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression
>   expression)    at Remotion.Linq.QueryableBase`1.GetEnumerator()    at
>   System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)

However, if I Write


`var person = new Person {Id = Guid.Empty};
session.Query().Where(x=> x == person).ToList();`

everything works fine. The only difference between the two classes and related mapping is that Address is mapped using the < class /> tag while Person belongs to an inheritance mapping, Party => Person and is mapped using < joined-subclass />

I know that I can rewrite the query using the Key fields rather than the object, however this is only a really simplified version of the problem and this solution is not applicable.

Any idea on this behavior ?

Thanks,
Marco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at QBE (Query By Example) :

- [NHibernate : Query by example on primary key produces "WHERE (1=1)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424699/nhibernate-query-by-example-on-primary-key-produces-where-1-1)
- [Mixing Likes and Equals with NHibernate Query-By-Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840773/mixing-likes-and-equals-with-nhibernate-query-by-example)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but how QBE relate to Linq To nHibernate ? am I missing something ?

Comment: From your question, it is what you're trying to achieve, using an object to perform a query.

Comment: Well, yes, that's correct, but your solution would imply to switch from LINQ to QBE, and unfortunately this is not feasible in my scenario.

Comment: ok. if you cannot switch to QBE, neither to query on properties, you should explain your whole problem, otherwise it will be difficult to assist you.

Comment: I've changed something and switched the query on properties and now it works. Maybe what I was trying to achieve it's something that nHibernate doesn't support. I'm marking the question as answered, due to this comments